# Does MySql Connector have a backwards compatibility?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core, mysql-connector

I am working on a dotnet project. The thing is, we have two MySql servers for a development and test stage. The people who set up the servers didn't use the same version. Test is 8.0.12 and development 8.0.30.

I would have suggested to update the test stage's sql server to the current (8.0.30), but that is not possible, due to other reasons.

Anyways the dotnet project was using the MySql Connector version 8.0.28 and it was connection to the development sql server. This was working completely fine.

However if you want to connect to the test server, according to our docs we should change that version to 8.0.12.

Now my question is, does that really matter? I unfortunately can't test it, because the test server is only internal and there is no possibility to perform a test for me. So it is basically just trying my luck and see in a deployment whether it worked or not.

I had the idea to use 8.0.30 for the connector and keep that as default, because obviously versions can be mismatched and work like the .30 and .28 example.

So my question is, can I use the MySql Connector version 8.0.30 for a MySql Server version 8.0.12?
Does MySql Connector have a backwards compatibility?

Thank you for your help in forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL Connector/NET (i.e., `MySql.Data`) is mostly backwards compatible with older server versions, but the developers do occasionally remove support for protocol features that older servers may still be using; for example:

- The IgnorePrepare connection-string option was deprecated in the Connector/NET 8.0.23 release and removed in the Connector/NET 8.0.24 release.
- The TLSv1 and TLSv1.1 connection protocols were previously deprecated in Connector/NET 8.0.26 and support for them is removed starting with 8.0.28.

As long as you're not using the deprecated features when connecting to your v8.0.12 test server, it should still work.